# Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Tags: admin, magento-1.9

Every time I access admin panel I get this error message.

I encountered this problem after I change base_url in core_config_data to http://magento.local/magento/, the previous is `http://localhosts/magento/`. Anyway I changed it back but the problem still be exist.

Note: Also add "127.0.0.1 magento.local" in host file

Here is a full trace

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted";i:1;s:2782:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(773): Zend_Uri::factory(' `http://localho...`')
1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(607): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Design\Package.php(349): Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Design\Package.php(503): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinBaseUrl(Array)
5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(1035): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinUrl('reset.css', Array)
6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\login.phtml(32): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getSkinUrl('reset.css')
7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
21 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
22 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
23 {main}";s:3:"url";s:25:"/magento/index.php/admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace from Magento's error.log to give some more info?

Comment: And please make sure you have cleared your cache between changes

Comment: Yes I have clear ie cache and magento cache by removing cache folder in Magento\var folder.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889286/magento-bug-illegal-scheme-supplied-only-alphanumeric-characters-are-permitte, your base url should have the full URI Schema so http://magento.local/magento/ should work. Be sure to turn of cache to be sure the correct base url is used

Comment: Here is a summay step I did 1.change url base to  http://magento.local/magento/ 2.remove cache 3.disable magento cache by change config in core_cache_option to be 0. The problem still be exist.  I'm very new in magento please advice

Comment: Please change it to `http://magento.local/magento/` and repeat step 2 and 3

Comment: Problem still be exist

Comment: And the error code is the same

Comment: You can control my machine by teamviewer if you want:)

Comment: Finally I have solved the problem. It is my stupid mistake. As Sander mentioned his solution work.

Comment: Please add your solution as answer to this question and accept it

Comment: I cannot post the solution because I have less 10 reputatio. What should I do?

Comment: May be could you please repost your solution again as answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the base_url is a valid URI Schema, so it should be `http://magento.local/magento/`.
Afterwards clear your cache and the issue should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check your url in `core_config_data` table it must have `http://` with full url like `http://smb.virtual.local/~ashwani/www/basemagento/`.