# Magento Admin page not accessible

Tags: admin, error

My store address working fine But magento admin page show error. the error is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in **app/etc/local.xml** in tag `<frontName>` - it should be only `<![CDATA[admin]]>`. Then find in the database, in table **core_config_data** - **admin/url/use_custom** and **admin/url/use_custom_path** and set them up to 0 (or directly run these queries:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 0 WHERE `path` = 'admin/url/use_custom';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 0 WHERE `path` = 'admin/url/use_custom_path';
```

). Finally remove all the content from **var/cache** and try again.

Comment: I apply this thing which you mention above but same problem admin page show error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Magento.Stackexchange question to see if you have the same issue

[Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26158/illegal-scheme-supplied-only-alphanumeric-characters-are-permitted)